# Can't renew chapter numbers in header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I have a somewhat complex preamble (because of the particular aesthetics I want), due to which I am using `scrpage2` package with the `book` document class. Everything was working fine, until I introduced an unnumbered chapter (the "Introduction"). This resulted in the header of the pages of the introduction to appear as "Contents".

In order to correct that, I resorted to the following fix:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]
```

This works fine. But I would like to get the chapter numbers back in the header for the rest of my book. Below is an MWE, where I have tried using `renewcommand{\chaptermark}` to get the chapter numbers back, but after trying out quite a few possible solutions, I still can't get it right ... it just keeps showing the chapter name only.

I want the header for the zero'th chapter to be "Introduction" instead of "Chapter 0: Introduction". But then, how can get `Chapter 1: Another Chapter` in the header instead of just `Another Chapter`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for testing

%% preamble based on http://www.khirevich.com/latex %%
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}

% Change chapter title font to sans-serif
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[activate={true,           % activate protrusion
                      nocompatibility % activate expansion
                     },
            final,                    % enable microtype (disable: "draft")
            tracking=true,            % activate tracking
            kerning=true,             % activate kerning
            spacing=true,             % activate spacing
            factor=1100,              % add 10% to protrusion (default: 1000)
            stretch=10,shrink=10]     % reduce streching/shrinking (default: 20/20)
            {microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
% below, define header for beginning of chapter and "normal" pages
\ohead[\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark]{\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{}

\DeclareMathVersion{mathchartertext}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathchartertext}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
            {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % format: \usefont{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}
            {}                                   % label
            {0em}                                % sep between label and title
            {\hspace{-0.4pt}
              \Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}
            }                                    % before code
            []                                   % after code

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]                       % shape
            {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} % format: sans-serif
            {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}          % label
            {20pt}                                    % sep
            {\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]           % before code

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\chaptermark{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}%
}
\lipsum[1-20]

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

*Note*: Much of the preamble is not necessary to reproduce the problem I am having. But I included these things in the MWE so that people understand why I am trying to do things this way instead of simply using the `scrbook` document class from Koma-script.

Comment: You shouldn't use both `sectsty` and `titlesec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be wanting continuous numbering across the document (which I like, having roman numbers in the front matter was justified in the olden times, now there's no need for them).

So just redefine `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to do what you need.

For having no page number in the chapter starting pages, modify `\chapter` rather than issuing `\thispagestyle{empty}` each time (which wouldn't work for `\tableofcontents` if it needs two or more pages).

Finally, don't load `sectsty` along with `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for testing

%% preamble based on http://www.khirevich.com/latex %%
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[activate={true,           % activate protrusion
                      nocompatibility % activate expansion
                     },
            final,                    % enable microtype (disable: "draft")
            tracking=true,            % activate tracking
            kerning=true,             % activate kerning
            spacing=true,             % activate spacing
            factor=1100,              % add 10% to protrusion (default: 1000)
            stretch=10,shrink=10]     % reduce streching/shrinking (default: 20/20)
            {microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
% below, define header for beginning of chapter and "normal" pages
\ohead[\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark]{\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{}

\DeclareMathVersion{mathchartertext}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathchartertext}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
            {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % format: \usefont{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}
            {}                                   % label
            {0em}                                % sep between label and title
            {\hspace{-0.4pt}
              \Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}
            }                                    % before code
            []                                   % after code

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]                       % shape
            {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} % format: sans-serif
            {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}          % label
            {20pt}                                    % sep
            {\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]           % before code

\makeatletter
% make \frontmatter and \mainmatter not to reset the numbering
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmatterfalse}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue}

% issue \thispagestyle{empty} instead of \thispagestyle{plain}
% when starting a chapter (needs etoolbox)
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{empty} % empty page style in the chapter starting pages
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{Thesis}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-20]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the layout of the chapter numbers in the header using package `scrpage2` or its successor `scrlayer-scrpage` you can  redefine `\chaptermarkformat`.

Here is a suggestion using `scrbook` and `scrlayer-scrpage` (the successor of `scrpage2`) but without the packages `sectsty`, `titlesec` and `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,
    DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false,
    chapterprefix
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for testing
%% preamble based on http://www.khirevich.com/latex %%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\DeclareMathVersion{mathchartertext}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathchartertext}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[activate={true,           % activate protrusion
                      nocompatibility % activate expansion
                     },
            final,                    % enable microtype (disable: "draft")
            tracking=true,            % activate tracking
            kerning=true,             % activate kerning
            spacing=true,             % activate spacing
            factor=1100,              % add 10% to protrusion (default: 1000)
            stretch=10,shrink=10]     % reduce streching/shrinking (default: 20/20)
            {microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp\ \thechapter:\enskip}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\normalsize\upshape}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[font=\Large]{section}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\hspace{-.4pt}\ \thesection\hspace{.6em}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=4.6\baselineskip plus \parskip,
    innerskip=20pt,
    afterskip=2.725\baselineskip plus.115\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip,
    font=\Huge,
    prefixfont=\huge
]{chapter}
% rule after chapter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\chapterheadendvskip{%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\vspace{2ex}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}}\par}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

With `book`, `titlesec` and `scrpage2` you can also redefine `\chaptermarkformat` to get the desired layout in the Header.

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername{} \thechapter:\enskip}
```

To get the unnumbered chapter in the page head use

```
\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
```

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for testing

%% preamble based on http://www.khirevich.com/latex %%
\usepackage[DIV=14,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[activate={true,           % activate protrusion
                      nocompatibility % activate expansion
                     },
            final,                    % enable microtype (disable: "draft")
            tracking=true,            % activate tracking
            kerning=true,             % activate kerning
            spacing=true,             % activate spacing
            factor=1100,              % add 10% to protrusion (default: 1000)
            stretch=10,shrink=10]     % reduce streching/shrinking (default: 20/20)
            {microtype}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
% below, define header for beginning of chapter and "normal" pages
\ohead[\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark]{\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername{} \thechapter:\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{}

\DeclareMathVersion{mathchartertext}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{mathchartertext}{OML}{mdbch}{m}{n}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
            {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont} % format: \usefont{encoding}{family}{series}{shape}
            {}                                   % label
            {0em}                                % sep between label and title
            {\hspace{-0.4pt}
              \Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}
            }                                    % before code
            []                                   % after code

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]                       % shape
            {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} % format: sans-serif
            {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}          % label
            {20pt}                                    % sep
            {\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]           % before code

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\clearpage

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

---

Note that `scrpage2` is deprecated. So I would suggested to use ist successor `scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\usepackage[headsepline,markcase=noupper,forceoverwrite]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\leftmark ~$\vert$ \pagemark}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername{} \thechapter:\enskip}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\normalsize\upshape}
```

The option `forceoverwrite` is needed because `titlesec` also defines the commands `\newpagestyle` and `\renewpagestyle`.